# OpenCV mat put method doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, opencv

I am trying to open grayscale image via OpenCV Mat object and I am getting odd results:
My code:

```
    Mat source = imageLoader.loadImage(srcImage);
    Mat mask   = imageLoader.loadImage(srcImageMask);
    if(!source.size().equals(mask.size())) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Size of mask and source differ"); 
    }

    //Convert to grayscale format 
    Mat sourceGrayScaleFormat = ImageConverter.convertToGrayscale(source); 
    Mat maskGrayScaleFormat   = ImageConverter.convertToGrayscale(mask); 
    

    int rows = sourceGrayScaleFormat.rows();
    int cols = sourceGrayScaleFormat.cols(); 
    for(int row = 0 ; row < rows; ++row) {
        for(int col = 0; col < cols; ++col) {
            double [] maskPixel = maskGrayScaleFormat.get(row, col);
            
            double [] data = sourceGrayScaleFormat.get(row, col);  
            if(holeUpperBound >  maskPixel[0]/normalizeFactor) {//According to the instructor - we should treat values below 128 values in the mask as hole pixel
                 data[0] = -1.0;     //Treat it a hole 
            } else {
                data[0] = data[0]/255.0;
            }
            sourceGrayScaleFormat.put(row, col, data ); 
            double [] data1 = sourceGrayScaleFormat.get(row, col);  
            
        }
    }
```

I expect that data1 will be equal to data, but is does not. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Define "getting odd results". | Let me make a guess: Instead of expected values,you only get the numbers 0, 1 or 255 (since I don't see you converting the datatype of the input `Mat`s, meaning they're still holding 8bit unsigned integers).

Comment: exactly. So, what exactly should I do?

Comment: BTW - The data numbers appears as double array

Comment: Yes, `get` returns array of doubles (irrespective of the actual data type of the Mat), because a `double` value can correctly represent any of the supported data types. | Since you want to store the value `-1.0` as well as values in range `[0.0,1.0]`, you should first convert the destination `Mat` to a floating point datatype (`CV_32FC1` or `CV_64FC1`). This can be accomplished using member function `Mat.convertTo`.